# Who's the right person to hire for exterior door repair?

Tags: doors, door-frame, contractors

I have an old(ish) house with a door that no longer seals tight against the frame. This is the door between my house and my uninsulated garage, so it's effectively an external door. (Also, it's probably not up to code.)

[image: the door]

[image: misaligned on top]

[image: misaligned on bottom (also water damage?)]

[image: misaligned on top but from the other side]

I've decided that this is not something I'll be able to fix myself; I want to hire someone who knows what they're doing. But who's the right person to hire for this - a handyman? a general contractor? something else? (This is in the USA.)

Thanks!

edit: I should clarify - I'm not struggling to find someone to do the work. I'm struggling to know which job title to start Googling in order to find someone to do the work.

Comment: Have a guess as to which became out of shape: door or frame … get a new door made / fitted.

Comment: In the US, these people are called carpenters.  They are very very VERY hard to find.  For some reason, the pay just isn't as good as being an electrician, plumber, or HVAC tech, so people give it up and move on.

Comment: Your neighbours/friends will probably know a decent person who is handy or a local contractor.   If just wanting better sealing, can probably just buy weather stripping at a local store.  A better door frame and/or door is a bit bigger job.

Comment: Do the other door while you're at it, with one that doesn't have a glass pane next to the handle. I don't need the combo to that key box; I could open that door with my fist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A carpenter, handyperson, or home repair specialist should all be able to handle that type of work. It's not something that requires any particular credentials or certifications. It's a matter of knowledge and good craftspersonship.

I see several repairs needing to be made:

- The door is sagging (or the wall has shifted). See how the gaps aren't uniform? They should be uniform and appropriately sized. The door jamb may need to be re-hung or just adjusted with some strategically placed screws, hidden behind hinges.
- Weatherstripping should be retrofitted. This doesn't look like it was intended to be an exterior door, but if it's sheltered from rain and some seals are applied it could do.
- A proper exterior threshold should be installed. While this door has a threshold, there's no bottom seal. It *can* work to simply install a sweep seal, but that's not ideal.
- Some aesthetic repairs could be made. It's difficult to repair veneer damaged to that extent, but a partial or full overlay could bring it back to beauty.

Answer (score 2):

That door could be repaired by handyman, but for the cost of that, you could get new pre-hung door (frame and door) that is also an outside door.

Looking at your door it is in a sad state (Lots of repairs needed.). Also the door threshold needs to be replaced.

New door will fix all you current problems and resist weather elements.

I recommend Fiberglass door or even steel with self closing hinges.

Get a handyman estimate for the repairs the alignment, new weather strips and threshold replacement, and compare that to the new door.

New door install can also be accomplished by same handyman, and they come with new threshold.

I get my handyman from Angi.com or from Handy.com

Comment: A steel door will be more likely to meet the fire resistance code for a door between the garage and living space and can be nicely insulated. It might not come with a self-closing hinge, but that can be easily retrofit.